# Output None with the correct tags while scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape from [Zalora](https://www.zalora.com.hk/men/clothing/shirt/?gender=men&dir=desc&sort=popularity&category_id=31&enable_visual_sort=1) for 3 things:
1. item brand
2. item name
3. item price(old)

Below is my initial attempt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def make_soup(url):
    html = requests.get(url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    return bsObj

soup = make_soup('https://www.zalora.com.hk/men/clothing/shirt/?gender=men&dir=desc&sort=popularity&category_id=31&enable_visual_sort=1')

itemBrand = soup.find("span",{"class":"b-catalogList__itmBrand fsm txtDark uc js-catalogProductTitle"})
itemName = soup.find("em",{"class":"b-catalogList__itmTitle fss"})
itemPrice = soup.find("span",{"class":"b-catalogList__itmPrice old"})

print(itemBrand, itemName, itemPrice)
```

Output:

```
None None None
```

Then I do further investigation:

```
productsCatalog = soup.find("ul",{"id":"productsCatalog"})
print(productsCatalog)
```

Output:

```
<ul class="b-catalogList__wrapper clearfix" id="productsCatalog">
```

This is the weird thing that puzzle me, there should be many tags within the ul tag (The 3 things I need are within those hidden tags), why are they not showing up?

Matter in fact, everything I try to scrape with BeautifulSoup within the ul tag have the output of None.

Comment: Try `curl` / `wget` / otherwise download the actual HTML and look at it. Chances are the actual content gets filled by JavaScript, and that's what you seen in your browser's inspector after the JS has run. Look at its network tab; maybe the data you're trying to scrape is directly served by some endpoint and loaded by JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this content is rendered by JavaScript, you can't access it using the `requests` module. You should use `selenium` to automate your browser and then use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the actual `html`.

This is how you do it using `selenium` with [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_driver = "path\\to\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver)

target = 'https://www.zalora.com.hk/men/clothing/shirt/?gender=men&dir=desc&sort=popularity&category_id=31&enable_visual_sort=1'
driver.get(target)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

print(soup.find("span",{"class":"b-catalogList__itmBrand fsm txtDark uc js-catalogProductTitle"}).get_text().strip())
print(soup.find("span", {'class': 'b-catalogList__itmPrice old'}).get_text().strip())
print(soup.find("em",{"class":"b-catalogList__itmTitle fss"}).get_text().strip())
```

Output:

```
JAXON
HK$ 149.00
EMBROIDERY SHORT SLEEVE SHIRT
```